# WHMCS custom function - update pay method error

Tags: whmcs

I'm trying to access `UpdatePayMethod` endpoint, but it always returns this error message :

```
Error Updating Remote Pay Method: Remote Storage Failed
```

I'm using stripe credit cards.

Can anyone give me a clue on what's happening?

Comment: Found this in WHMCS Forums: https://whmcs.community/topic/300186-error-updating-remote-pay-method-remote-storage-failed/?ct=1591447221

Comment: yea, I posted the question there too :)